# How to drag a canvas with helper 'clone'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a simple HTML canvas

```
<div class='circle'>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</div>
```

with style

```
.circle {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

and script

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();

$('.circle').draggable({
    helper: 'clone' // Remove this line to make it draggable
});
```

It seems that I cannot use the helper option where i want to keep a copy of the circle at the original position when i drag it around. The draggable will work only if i remove the helper option. This only happened to canvas, not if I draw the circle using css. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marsant/s5Jee/). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately when you clone a canvas element, this doesn't copy over the image data. You may want to instead export your canvas data as a data url and clone the image instead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/Bdpq9/2/

```
<div class='circle'>
</div>

var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
var url = c.toDataURL();
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src",url);
$(".circle").append(img);

$('.circle').draggable({
    helper: 'clone' // Remove this line to make it draggable
});
```

Comment: Looks working for now. I will need to play with it more, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That is because cloning only clones the canvas *element*, not the content of it (canvas is a special element in this regard). You can see evidence of this by [marking the canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/s5Jee/1/).

You will need to redraw the content from the original canvas onto the cloned instance:

```
/// you need to get these objects in advance, then:
clonedContext.drawImage(originalCanvas, 0, 0);
```